# Check if named pipe is open for reading

Tags: bash, shell, fifo

Right now, I have this crappy check to see if a named pipe is being read from:

```
is_named_pipe_being_read() {

    local named_pipe="$1" 
    echo "unlocked" > "$named_pipe" & 
    pid="$!"
    # Wait a short amount of time
    sleep 0.25
    # Kill the background process. If kill succeeds, then
    # the write was blocked 
    ( kill -PIPE "$pid" ) &> /dev/null
}
```

if the kill works (exits with 0) then it means that nobody was reading from the pipe.

But instead of having a 0.25 second delay and starting up an unnecessary process, I am looking for a way to check the named pipe to see if it's opened for reading? Is there some way to determine if something is reading from it?

**Note**: I can't read from the pipe in this call, I can only write to it (because with named pipes the order at which readers are attached does not seem to be respected - or perhaps it's the most recent reader that gets the data, not the oldest reader).

Answer (score 5):

```
if /bin/echo unlocked 1<>fifo >fifo; then
    there are readers
else
    no there ain\'t
fi

is_named_pipe_being_read(){ /bin/echo unlocked 1<>"$1" >"$1"; }
```

The `/bin/echo` will be killed by a `SIGPIPE` and return a non-zero status if there are no readers.

You cannot use the built-in `echo` (even in a subshell) because the `SIGPIPE` will be either caught or kill the whole shell.

Just like the version from the OP, this is destructive. If you have GNU dd, you can just try opening the file with `O_NONBLOCK`, as from `C`:

```
is_named_pipe_being_read(){ dd oflag=nonblock conv=notrunc,nocreat count=0 of="$1" 2>/dev/null; }
```

Bu this is not much better; if there are other writers to the pipe, the automatic close of the fifo at the command exit will cause all the readers to get an EOF.

**Note:** using named pipes is more of a matter of masochism or standard pedantry [1]. The BSD sockets api as implemented by the unix domain sockets is incomparably better (that's why it rules the world ;-)), and there are programs like the newer versions of `netcat` which make it kind of usable from the shell too.

[1] which is defeated in examples like the above or [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/522881/308316) by the fact that opening a fifo in rw mode is "undefined" according to the standard, though implemented the same in most systems since 30 years ago or so)).

Comment: yes I agree, named pipes are probably the most overrated thing I can think of - I always have problems when I try to use them. with unix domain sockets, I would need multiple servers listening from the same socket - which isn't possible. But multiple "servers" can `cat` the same fifo, so that works out better.

Comment: can you explain how this works a little bit more? Why file descriptor 1?

Comment: Because the `<>` redirection will use the stdin (0) by default (except in `ksh93`, as explained in the [linked answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/522881/308316) from Stéphane Chazelas).

Comment: Right but why does it have to be 1 instead of 0? (stdout instead of stdin)

Comment: Because it has to be the same fd as the 2nd redirection. When you write something like `cmd >file`, what happens is that the shell opens `file`, gets a file descriptor (`fd`) and then calls `dup2(fd, 1)`. The `dup2()` will close the file object fd 1 was pointing to before, and that *has to be* the same named pipe, otherwise the process will keep holding an open handle to its reading end, and no `SIGPIPE` will be generated.

Comment: thanks I will try this out, if you see anything suspicious about the C program in the other answer lmk, trying to learn C in general

Comment: Instead of exploiting the fact that `dup2` is closing the `oldfd`, you can use another fd and close it explicitly with the same effect: `/bin/echo 7<>fifo >fifo 7>&-`.

Comment: thanks so I will take your suggestion of using UDS - but I guess I am not sure if using netcat and bash is very expressive? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/522944/how-can-a-client-talk-to-another-client-using-unix-domain-sockets

Comment: See also `socat` for a more usable interface to sockets in shells. `zsh` also has builtin support for Unix domain (also TCP) sockets

Comment: Note that if there were some readers, but no writers yet, that is when the readers are blocked on their `open(RD_ONLY)`, the `/bin/echo unlocked 1<>fifo >fifo` would unblock those readers and make them read that `unlocked\n` text and then see EOF. Whatever those readers were meant to be using the fifo for, they'll end up reading a "unlocked" message from it instead. It's quite an intrusive way to test if a pipe has a reader. That may be OK for the OP though as he's already doing it in his question.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas yeah, that's what the OP was using. A much more interesting question would be if there's any way to find the processes sleeping in an open(2) by the path of the file they're trying to open. I don't think that `lsof` is able to do that.

Comment: No, lsof wouldn't as the process has not gotten a fd on it yet. That's probably a job for a kernel debugger, `stap` or the like at least on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I stole this C program from https://stackoverflow.com/a/20694422/5047085:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#define SERVFIFO "/Users/alex/.locking/ql/locks/a/fifo.lock"
#define FILE_MODE (S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH)

void syserr(const char *str){
    perror(str);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    umask(0);

    // try to open for write with no readers

    int fdw = open(SERVFIFO, O_WRONLY | O_NONBLOCK);

    if (fdw == -1){
      syserr("non-blocking open for write with no readers failed");
    }

    // create a reader - the process itself - non-blocking

    int fdr = open(SERVFIFO, O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
    if (fdr == -1){
      syserr("non-blocking open for read no writers failed");
    }

    // try again to open for write but this time with a reader
    fdw = open(SERVFIFO, O_WRONLY | O_NONBLOCK);

    if (fdw == -1){
      syserr("non-blocking open with readers failed");
    }


    printf("non-blocking open for write succeeded\n");

    close(fdw);
    close(fdr);

}
```

if it exits with 0, that means someone is reading from the named pipe already? And if it exits with 1, it means nobody is reading from it.

This could be wrong, but basic testing says it works. The fifo path is hardcoded in the program above.

Comment: If you obtained this code from someone else, state the source. Otherwise this is plagiarism, and stating that you stole it doesn't help any.

Comment: @muru I guess he stole this code [from a friend](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=asking%20for%20a%20friend)

Comment: @mosvy I doubt it. Google the messages in the code and you get what's either the source or a copy of it: https://codeday.me/jp/qa/20190404/549503.html

Comment: I stand corrected.

Comment: also this answer works and serves as a good answer to OP

Comment: @MrCholo I'm not sure why you're suggesting an edit as to where Alexander Mills got their code from, but I would suggest a comment on the Answer, allowing the OP to make the attribution they believe is correct.

Comment: Well it's fixed now, no big deal, I know 100% that this was the original source