# How can a client talk to another client using unix domain sockets?

Tags: socket, netcat, socat, unix-sockets, nc

Using bash we might have something like this with netcat:

```
nc -lk -U /my/fifo | while read line; do
   # line => {"client_id":123}
done;
```

clients send data like this:

```
echo '{"client_id":123,"data":"foo"}' | nc -U /my/fifo
```

and clients wait for data like this:

```
echo '{"client_id":123}' | nc -U /my/fifo | while read line; do

done;
```

**my question**  - how can I send data from one client to another client, without involving all the clients? On the "server", I would need to store a reference to each client, so when I get a message from one client, I know who to forward the message to? How can I store a reference to the clients that are currently connected? Just like websockets, I want to create channels, where anyone registered to that channel will get the message.

Comment: and as an aside, if a netcat client sends a message to the netcat server, I am not sure how to respond directly (write back to that one client).

Comment: Just commenting: There is an uneven number of double quotes in the text strings that you are giving to `nc`.

Comment: Thanks, quotes fixed as far as the OP, more of a conceptual question here

Answer (score -1):

So here is the thing, I guess I can respond to clients with:

```
echo "this is the response" | nc -lk -U /my/fifo
```

but the whole point is how do I respond differently depending on who the client is? I mean how can you create something very useful if there is no logic based on the client request etc?

My only guess is to have two servers:

```
nc -lk -U /my/fifo1 | while read line; do

  # custom logic goes here

done > nc -lk -U /my/fifo2
```

so then clients connect with:

```
echo '{"client_id":123}' | nc -U /my/fifo1 

nc -U /my/fifo2 | while read line; do

done;
```

this betrays what I know about how tcp and unix domain sockets work with Node.js etc, but I guess with bash we have to do it this way?

I also think to avoid race conditions might have to put the above two commands in a single pipe somehow.

Comment: This does not look like an answer. This should probably be an edit to your question.

Comment: partial answer, I don't think the question needs to be longer